# JS: Merge objects with identical title value into new array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I'm trying to get some data from different collections and return them as one object array, but I need to merge objects with identical title.

```
'search': function(value) {
    const res1 = Col1.find({ title: new RegExp(value, 'i') }, { fields: { title: 1, type: 1 } }).fetch() || [],
          res2 = Col2.find({ title: new RegExp(value, 'i') }, { fields: { title: 1, type: 1 } }).fetch() || []

    let result = res1.concat(res2)

    return result
}
```

Assume the first collection will give me 'cars' for `type`-field, and the second gives me 'animals'.

In case there is an identical title, I need to change `type`-field and add some content.

```
{ _id: 1, title: 'mercedes', type: 'cars' }
{ _id: 2, title: 'monkey', type: 'animals' }
{ _id: 3, title: 'jaguar', type: 'cars' }
{ _id: 4, title: 'jaguar', type: 'animals' }
```

Should be transformed to

```
{ _id: 1, title: 'mercedes', type: 'cars' }
{ _id: 2, title: 'monkey', type: 'animals' }
{ title: 'jaguar', type: 'multiple', results: [
    { _id: 3, title: 'jaguar', type: 'cars' }
    { _id: 4, title: 'jaguar', type: 'animals' }
] }
```

Comment: Looks like you should set up your database differently from the start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table `titles` for the same titles and assign the item to an array and save the index.

```js
var data = [{ _id: 1, title: 'mercedes', type: 'cars' }, { _id: 2, title: 'monkey', type: 'animals' }, { _id: 3, title: 'jaguar', type: 'cars' }, { _id: 4, title: 'jaguar', type: 'animals' }],
    result = data.reduce(function (titles) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (titles[a.title]) {
                if (titles[a.title].results.length === 1) {
                    r[titles[a.title].index] = { title: a.title, type: 'multiple', results: titles[a.title].results };
                }
                titles[a.title].results.push(a);
            } else {
                titles[a.title] = { index: r.push(a) - 1, results: [a] };
            }
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could move the hash table outside of the closure.

```js
var data = [{ _id: 1, title: 'mercedes', type: 'cars' }, { _id: 2, title: 'monkey', type: 'animals' }, { _id: 3, title: 'jaguar', type: 'cars' }, { _id: 4, title: 'jaguar', type: 'animals' }],
    titles = Object.create(null),
    result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        if (titles[a.title]) {
            if (titles[a.title].results.length === 1) {
                r[titles[a.title].index] = { title: a.title, type: 'multiple', results: titles[a.title].results };
            }
            titles[a.title].results.push(a);
        } else {
            titles[a.title] = { index: r.push(a) - 1, results: [a] };
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: eslint gives me a 'wrap-iife' error for the data.reduce line: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/wrap-iife I don't understand this...

Comment: maybe the second approach does fit eslint.

Answer (score 0):

You can get count for each title and then create a new array using `filter` by each title:

```js
const a = [
  { _id: 1, title: 'mercedes', type: 'cars' },
  { _id: 2, title: 'monkey', type: 'animals' },
  { _id: 3, title: 'jaguar', type: 'cars' },
  { _id: 4, title: 'jaguar', type: 'animals' }
],
  titles = [...new Set(a.map(({title}) => title))] // count for each title
    .map(t => Object.assign({[t]: a.filter(({title}) => title === t).length})) // current title count
    .reduce((acc, v) => Object.assign(acc, v), {}); // form an object for convenience
    
const res = Object.keys(titles) // for each title
  .reduce((acc, t) => (titles[t] === 1) // if not multiple
    ? acc.concat(a.filter(({title}) => title === t)) // add the element
    : acc.concat(Object.assign({title: t, type: 'multiple', // form 'multiple' element
     results: a.filter(({title}) => title === t)}))
  , [])
  
console.log(res)
```